# Finding rendered control id

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to find a specific control on a C# asp.net webpage that is having an issue on `DataBind()`.

The stack trace shows ASP."page"`_aspx_DataBinding_control27(Object sender, EventArgs e)`,

however I am unable to determine which control on the page is actually control27. All searches I have found point me to `FindControl`, which is not what I need.

I know what the error is, but I am unable to see which control is causing the error to resolve.

Comment: Look a little farther up the stack trace to see what method is calling `DataBind`.  That should help you narrow it down.  If you are running in debug mode, you should get line numbers as well.

Comment: It occurs on a Timer_Tick event that is used to refresh the page every 3 minutes. The line number is listed in the stack trace and that is the line doing the DataBind() and then updates the update panel right after. I have this inclosed in a try/catch block. If an exception occurs I receive an email from the client system with the stack trace. Unfortunately I am unable to find which data bound control is referenced by control27 when the page is rendered.